# PySpark - Are Spark DataFrame Arrays Different Than Python Lists?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If I have a Spark `DataFrame` containing `arrays`, can I use Python List methods on these arrays through a UDF? How can I take the Spark `DataFrame` `array<double>` and turn it into a Python list?

Below is an example, with a few UDFs. I am not sure why taking the max works, but taking `len` does not. Ultimately, I want to make a new column with sampled values from the original array column. That also gets an error about expecting two arguments, bonus points if you can help with that too!

I have the following Spark `DataFrame`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType
import random

df = sc.parallelize([Row(name='Joe',scores=[1.0,2.0,3.0]),
Row(name='Mary', scores=[3.0]),
Row(name='Mary', scores=[4.0,7.1])]).toDF()
>>> df.show()
+----+---------------+
|name|         scores|
+----+---------------+
| Joe|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]|
|Mary|          [3.0]|
|Mary|     [4.0, 7.1]|
+----+---------------+
>>> df
DataFrame[name: string, scores: array<double>]
def sampleWithReplacement(listIn,samples):
    tempList = array()
    count=0
    while (count<samples):
        tempList.append(random.sample(listIn,1)[0])
        count=count+1
    return tempList

def maxArray(listIn):
    return max(listIn)

def lenArray(listIn):
    return len(listIn)
sampUDF=udf(sampleWithReplacement,ArrayType())
maxUDF=udf(maxArray,IntegerType())
lenUDF=udf(lenArray,IntegerType())

>>> df.withColumn("maxCol",maxUDF(df.scores)).show()
+----+---------------+------+
|name|         scores|maxCol|
+----+---------------+------+
| Joe|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]|  null|
|Mary|          [3.0]|  null|
|Mary|     [4.0, 7.1]|  null|
+----+---------------+------+

>>> df.withColumn("maxCol",lenUDF(df.scores)).show()
+----+---------------+------+
|name|         scores|maxCol|
+----+---------------+------+
| Joe|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]|     3|
|Mary|          [3.0]|     1|
|Mary|     [4.0, 7.1]|     2|
+----+---------------+------+
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR** When you have a choice always prefer built-in functions over `udf`. To compute length use `size` (aliased as `length)` method:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import length, size 

df.withColumn("len", size("scores"))
```

For small arrays you can try

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sort_array

df.withColumn("max", sort_array("scores", False)[0])
```

but of course it is not a good choice for large collections.

> Are Spark DataFrame Arrays Different Than Python Lists?

Internally they are different because there are Scala objects. When accessed in `udf` there are plain Python lists. So what is going wrong?

Let's look at the types. `scores` column is `array<double>`. When converted to Python types this results in a `List[float]`. When you call `max` you get a `float` on the output.

Yet you declare return types as `IntegerType`. Because `float` cannot be converted to integer loss of precision result is undefined an you get `NULL`. Correct choice of the return type is either `DoubleType` or `FloatType`:

```
maxf = udf(lambda xs: max(xs), FloatType())
maxd = udf(lambda xs: max(xs), DoubleType())

(sc
    .parallelize([("Joe", [1.0, 2.0, 3.0])])
    .toDF(["name", "scores"])
    .select("*", maxf("scores"), maxd("scores")))
```

with result:

```
+----+---------------+----------------+----------------+
|name|         scores|<lambda>(scores)|<lambda>(scores)|
+----+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| Joe|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]|             3.0|             3.0|
+----+---------------+----------------+----------------+
```

and schema:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- scores: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- <lambda>(scores): float (nullable = true)
 |-- <lambda>(scores): double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to cast this kind of array to String, without leaving the field like `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@xxxx` ? Convert it to string with elements delimited by "," should be perfect.